# Is S3 Object's Metadata strongly consistent

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata, consistency, eventual-consistency

S3 Objects have eventual consistency for overwrites PUTS and DELETES as mentioned here - http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ

Is this applicable for both S3 Object and metadata or Object's metadata is read after write consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both S3 object (or data) and metadata follow same consistency model.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html :

> "Objects are the fundamental entities stored in Amazon S3. **Objects
>   consist of object data and metadata.** The data portion is opaque to
>   Amazon S3. "

As consistency model is about objects (and not objects data) so yes metadata complies with the model as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, not always. Just as with object data, object metadata sometimes is eventually consistent, not strongly consistent.

Remainder of answer copied from [Quick Explanation Of The S3 Consistency Model](https://codeburst.io/quick-explanation-of-the-s3-consistency-model-6c9f325e3f82) 
      -- codeburst.io blog post 2018-02-10

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) says:

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.

Note "the caveat".

It means you can observe the following sequence of events:

```
GET /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 404
PUT /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 200
GET /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 404
```

or this one:

```
PUT /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 200
PUT /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 200 (new content)
GET /key-prefix/cool-file.jpg 200 (old content returned)
```

which is not strongly consistent.

Comment: I think this was correct at the time of writing but they've since updated to full consistency with no caveats: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/